# Android Eclipse: Preparing a .hprof file for use with MAT

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, heap-memory

I am trying to use MAT to analyze a file from my Android App. with I am doing the following

1. Running my application on my phone
2. Using it for awhile
3. Pressing the "Dump HPROF file" button in DDMS in eclipse (The resulting file shows up in eclipse)
4. I then try to save the file as something but I get the following error:

"Save could not be completed. Some characters cannot be mapped using "Cp1252" character encoding. Either change the encoding or remove the characters which are not supported by the "Cp1252" character encoding."

How do I do what the error message is suggesting?

I am working on Windows 7, Eclipse  Helios Service Release 2, Android version Version: 11.0.0.v201105251008-128486

Comment: Did you try changing the encoding of your Eclipse project? To UTF-8 for example?

Comment: Thank you, it worked, please post your suggestion as an answer so I can check it (i.e. go to winodw->preferences->Workspace and in the text file pane select utf-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the encoding of your Eclipse project, for example to UTF-8.

You can do this in Eclipse for a single project by right-clicking on the project -> Properties -> Resource -> Text file encoding

Or to change the default encoding for all projects in your workspace, go to the menu Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Text file encoding